# BlogPosting Publisher Logo 'logo.itemtype has an invalid value' on Google Structured Data Testing Tool

Tags: schema.org, microdata, google-rich-snippets-tool

The following runs through the [Google Structured Data Testing Tool](https://search.google.com/structured-data/testing-tool) as expected:

```html
<div>
    <div itemprop="publisher" itemscope id="organization-example" itemtype="https://schema.org/Organization">
        <a itemprop="url" href="https://example.com">
            <img itemprop="image logo" src="https://example.com/images/logo.png" alt="LOGO">
            <span itemprop="name">EXAMPLE</span>
            <span itemprop="description">This is an EXAMPLE</span>
        </a>
    </div>
</div>

<div itemscope itemtype="https://schema.org/WebPage" itemref="organization-example">
</div>
```

But when I try using a `BlogPosting` it breaks the `logo` property:

```html
<div>
    <div itemprop="publisher" itemscope id="organization-example" itemtype="https://schema.org/Organization">
        <a itemprop="url" href="https://example.com">
            <img itemprop="image logo" src="https://example.com/images/logo.png" alt="LOGO">
            <span itemprop="name">EXAMPLE</span>
            <span itemprop="description">This is an EXAMPLE</span>
        </a>
    </div>
</div>

<article
    itemscope
    itemtype="https://schema.org/BlogPosting"
    itemref="organization-example"
>
</article>
```

With the error:

> `https://example.com/images/logo.png` (The attribute logo.itemtype has an invalid value.)

Can anyone explain why? And what steps I could take to fix it?

Comment: You should avoid using `itemprop` on the same line as a `itemtype`, since publisher is a child of Organization, WebPage and BlogPosting. Better to use `<body itemscope  itemtype="https://schema.org/Organization">` then `<article itemscope
    itemtype="https://schema.org/BlogPosting">` `<span itemprop="publisher">` etc... There shouldn't be a need to repeat the logo multiple times, particularly in a blog post.

Comment: @SimonHayter Thanks, but Publisher isn't a child of Organization, and the Organization is at the top of the WebPage so I wanted to reference it from the BlogPosting.. Are you suggesting the structure Organization->BlogPosting->Publisher? This seems incorrect.

Comment: @SimonHayter Also [https://schema.org/WebPage](https://schema.org/WebPage) and the whole site is riddled with examples doing exactly that.. `itemprop` on the same line as `itemtype`.

Comment: Blonde moment, I'll totally wrong. I'll take a look in a later and get back to you :)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Turns out, because `BlogPosting` is one of the types supported by Google as a possible Rich Snippet, they apply more validation:

[Google Search Documentation Guidelines for Articles](https://developers.google.com/search/docs/data-types/articles)

This requires an Article's Publisher's `logo` to be of type `ImageObject` and have a `width` and `height` in pixels. `BlogPosting` is a subtype of `Article`.

This updated snippet validates through the [Google Structured Data Testing Tool](https://search.google.com/structured-data/testing-tool):

```html
<div id='web-page-example' itemprop="mainEntityOfPage" itemscope itemtype="https://schema.org/WebPage" itemref="headline-example">
    <div>
        <div itemprop="publisher" itemscope id="organization-example" itemtype="https://schema.org/Organization">
            <a itemprop="url" href="https://example.com">
                <span itemprop="logo" itemscope itemtype="https://schema.org/ImageObject">
                   <img itemprop="url" src="https://example.com/images/logo.png" alt="LOGO">
                   <meta itemprop="width" content="600">
                   <meta itemprop="height" content="60">
                </span>   
                <span itemprop="name">EXAMPLE</span>
                <span itemprop="description">This is an EXAMPLE</span>
            </a>
        </div>
    </div>  
    <div
        id="blog-posting-example"
        itemprop="mainEntity"
        itemscope
        itemtype="https://schema.org/BlogPosting"
        itemref="organization-example web-page-example"
    >
        <span itemprop="author" itemscope itemtype="https://schema.org/Person">
            <span itemprop="name">Example Author</span>
        </span>
        <time itemprop="datePublished" datetime="2016-05-09T11:40:04+02:00">9th May 2016</time>
        <time itemprop="dateModified" datetime="2016-05-09T11:40:04+02:00">9th May 2016</time>
        <h1 id="headline-example" itemprop="name headline">Example Headline</h1>
        <span itemprop="image" itemscope itemtype="https://schema.org/ImageObject">
            <img itemprop="url" src="https://example.com/images/blog.png" alt="LOGO">
            <meta itemprop="width" content="800">
            <meta itemprop="height" content="400">
        </span>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 11):

A brilliant and helpful answer by @Arth above.

To complement the answer above (not compete with it), here is the same *Structured Data* using the same **schema.org** vocabulary, but this time in `JSON-LD`:

```
    "publisher": {
        "@type": "Organization",
        "name": "myOrganization",
        "logo": {
            "@type": "ImageObject",
            "name": "myOrganizationLogo",
            "width": "60",
            "height": "600",
            "url": "http://my-organization.org/my-logo.png"
        }
    }
```

**N.B.** According to https://developers.google.com/search/docs/data-types/articles

> 1. The logo should be a rectangle, not a square.
> 2. The logo should fit in a `60x600px` rectangle., and either be exactly `60px` high (preferred), or exactly `600px` wide. (For example,
>    `450x45px` would not be acceptable, even though it fits in the
>    `600x60px` rectangle.)